# Unable to echo Radio Button Values

Tags: php

I would like to ask if Radio button could be echo out for my edit page?
Currently I am typing this way.

```
<td>
<input type="radio" name="priority" value="<?php echo $row['priority']; ?> " />Immediate
<input type="radio" name="priority" value="<?php echo $row['priority']; ?> " />Urgent
<input type="radio" name="priority" value="<?php echo $row['priority']; ?> " />Routine
</td>
```

Was wondering if I did something wrong?

Comment: <td><input type="radio" name="priority" value="<?php echo $row['priority']; ?> " />Immediate
                    <input type="radio" name="priority" value="<?php echo $row['priority']; ?> " />Urgent
                    <input type="radio" name="priority" value="<?php echo $row['priority']; ?> " />Routine</td>


Sorry these are my codes.

Comment: what are they contents(value) of $row['priority'];

Comment: changed my codes to 'checked'

Answer (score 0):

To have a radio button checked you have to add the attribute "checked" like that:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
```

versus

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
```

So you need to compare the value you want to populate into the edit form with the value of the radio button and if they match, then echo out the attribute "checked".

Here is an example using shorthand if:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php ('male' == $row['priority']) ? 'checked' : ''?> /> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php ('female' == $row['priority']) ? 'checked' : ''?> /> Female<br>
</form>
```

Comment: I have 3 priorities, immediate urgent and routine, now its sucessfully showing immediate as a button. However for urgent and routine is showing unidentified index any idea why?
Here are my code
<td><input type="radio" name="priority" value= "Immediate"<?php ('Immediate' == $row['priority']) ?'checked' :'' ?>  />Immediate
                    <input type="radio" name="priority" value= "Urgent" <?php ('Urgent' == $row['Urgent']) ?'checked' :'' ?>  />Urgent
                    <input type="radio" name="priority" value= "Routine"<?php ('Routine' == $row['Routine']) ?'checked' :'' ?>  />Routine</td>

Comment: Can you please send us the output of the following: `<?php var_dump($row) ?>`

Answer (score 0):

use this method, hope this help

```
<td>
<input type="radio" name="priority" value= "Immediate"<?php echo ('Immediate' == $row['priority']) ?'checked=checked' :'' ?> />Immediate 
<input type="radio" name="priority" value= "Urgent" <?php echo ('Urgent' == $row['Urgent']) ?'checked=checked' :'' ?> />Urgent 
<input type="radio" name="priority" value= "Routine"<?php echo ('Routine' == $row['Routine']) ?'checked=checked' :'' ?> />Routine</td>
```

Comment: try this : print_r($row) then paste your result here.